# Calculating SVD in ILnumerics

Tags: svd, ilnumerics

```
    ILArray<double> CU = new double[256, 256];
    ILArray<double> CV = new double[256, 256];
    ILArray<double> S = ILMath.svd(matrixC, CU, CV, true, true);
```

While Calculating SVD in ILnumerics,I am not getting the Correct Value of S as compare to result obtain from Matlab.But I am getting the Correct Value of U and V.

Why is this so ?? I am doing something wrong on this.Please Help.

Thanks and Regards,

Subin Bajracharya

Comment: Why do you think they are wrong? How many 'correct' values are there?

Comment: I am getting all the wrong Values of S

Answer (score 1):

SVDs results are not unique. In order to judge the correctness, consider testing for equaltiy of the result of multiplying the output of SVD with the original matrix, recognizing round off errors.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition